# HTML Table as Flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to denote a HTML table as a flex item?

For example:

## HTML:

```
<div id="flex-container">
  <table class="flex-container__table"> 
  </table>

  <table class="flex-container__table"> 
  </table>
</div>
```

## CSS:

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
}
.flex-container__table {
    flex: 0.3;
}
```

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, well, clearly it is...but the effect may not be what you are after.

```css
table {
  border:1px solid grey;
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing: 2px;
}

td {
  padding: 1em;
  border:1px solid green;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.wrap table {
  flex:1;
  margin: 0 1em;
 background: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <table>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr></table>
  
  <table>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr></table>

</div>
```

Note that even with `flex:1`* applied the table does not expand to fill the remaining space.

I suspect that to expand the table you would have to extend the flexing to the `tr/td` which would,  essentially, negate the point of a table in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm looking to understand the actual reason behind the table not expanding to fill the space. I'll do some more research.

Comment: I suspect because it still has `display:table` applied...if you change it to `display:block` the **background** expands but the cells do not. There is no `display:flex-item` (I believe) to override the default `display` style.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your css selector for div. That should be "#".

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Please try to comment instead.

Comment: @PanwenWang You need about 100 reputation to comment, he only has 1. In this case Stackoverflow is at fault, not him.

Comment: @FireFuro99 Ah, it's just SO asking me to review...